If the universe at one point had a 'superforce' composed of all fundamental forces, would that force have a boson, or bosons, that mediate the force?
I know that every fundamental force has a boson that is responsible for mediating the force, those being the Photon, Gluon, $W^-$, $W^+$, $Z$, and possibly graviton. I also know that during the re-unification of the weak and electromagnetic forces, there are 4 massless bosons that mediate the electroweak force. So would this be the same for adding together the strong force with the electroweak force, and adding that unified force with gravity?

I'm not sure why this was closed. It seems clear enough to me and my answer would be the same as Hokon's.

Questions starting with "If the universe" are usually not of much meaning, that's why it is down voted.

Due diligence.


I know that every fundamental force has a boson that is responsible for mediating the forces. . . so would this be the same for adding together the strong force with the electroweak force, and adding that unified force with gravity?

Yes, in various Grand Unified Theories (GUTs) where the strong nuclear force is united with the electroweak force, yes there are a number of X and Y bosons that mediate the grand unified force ("superforce" as you call it). The number of X and Y bosons depends on the specific GUT one is looking at. Keep in mind that we haven't settled on which GUT is right, if any.
Gravity is more complicated, because of the variety of attempts at understanding gravity in a quantum mechanical way and/or unifying it with the other three fundamental forces (assuming that any of these approaches are the right way to go).
So "yes" regarding Grand Unification, adding gravity is even more speculative.
